# SQL Mail to send emails to users specified in a query only

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've about 1 month of experience when it comes to SQL and I wanted to send emails to customers based on query criteria. The challange I have is that the emails should only go to users emails that show up in the query. Below is an example of the data. I have no idea what I should do to setup the auto emailing based on a query. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My query would look like this,

```
select *
from [Tbl]
where [Date Certificate is Expiring] 
Between getdate()-372 AND getdate()-371
```

OUTPUT:

USER ID | Email | Date Certificate is Expiring

NOTE: I do not have access to Visual Basic, SSRS, SSIS, or any other tool than Database Engine and dbMail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create DB mail profile first, then put it into below query:

```
DECLARE @MailRecipients NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @MailRecipients = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ';' + t.Email 
    FROM [Tbl] t 
    WHERE t.[Date Certificate is Expiring] BETWEEN GETDATE()-372 AND GETDATE()-371 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
;

IF COALESCE(@MailRecipients,'') <> ''
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = ..., -- <-- you have to create DBMailProfile first
            @recipients = @MailRecipients,
            @subject = 'Email about expiring stuff',
            @body_format = 'HTML',
            @body = 'Hi there, your something is expired',
            @importance = 'Normal' 
END
```

Comment: This worked for the most part. IF COALESCE didn't want to work, but that's not a problem :) 

Thank you!

Comment: I stand corrected, forgot to include the semi colon 
:) that works too